# The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request. J2EE

Tags: java, servlets

I have a problem with my simply app in J2EE. This is login form. When I type login and password I get

> The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from
>   fulfilling this request.

My files:

#### Login.java

```
package facebookConnection.servlets;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import facebookConnection.classes.Validate;

import java.sql.*;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class Login
 */
@WebServlet("/Login")
public class Login extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        String login = request.getParameter("login");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");

        if(Validate.checkUser(login,password))
        {
            RequestDispatcher rs = request.getRequestDispatcher("Welcome");
            rs.forward(request, response);
        }
        else
        {
            out.println("Username or password nieprawidłowy");
            RequestDispatcher rs = request.getRequestDispatcher("index.html");
            rs.include(request, response);
        }
    }
}
```

#### Validate.java

```
package facebookConnection.classes;

import java.sql.*;

public class Validate {
    public static boolean checkUser(String login, String password) {
        boolean st = false;
        try {
            //loading drivers for mysql
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

            //creating connection with database
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/facebook_connections","root","pass");
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("select * from users where login=? and password=?");
            ps.setString(1, login);
            ps.setString(2, password);
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            st = rs.next();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return st;
    }
}
```

#### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Login form</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="login" method="post">
            Login: <input type="text" name="login" /><br/>
            Password: <input type="text" name="password" /><br/>
            <input type="submit" value="login" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

#### Welcome.java

```
package facebookConnection.servlets;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.sql.*;

public class Welcome extends HttpServlet {

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("Welcome user");
    }
}
```

#### web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>facebookConnect</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Login</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>facebookConnection.servlets.Login</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Welcome</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>facebookConnection.servlets.Welcome</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Login</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/login</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Welcome</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/welcome</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Stack Trace

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Error instantiating servlet class facebookConnection.servlets.Login
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
root cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: facebookConnection.servlets.Login
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1702)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Can anybody help me with it?

Comment: its `ClassNotFoundException` are you sure `Login` class is in claspath?

Comment: Your WAR packaging and deployment can't be correct.  If you're depending on Eclipse to do it for you, better to learn how without the IDE first.